# What cars can be used in the GT5 single model online racing?

Tags: gran-turismo-5

A bunch of friends have regular weekly GT5 racing using the "Lounge" facility.

Last night I experimented with a "single model" race. Where you can set that everyone has identical cars in the "Regulation" menu.

Even if the person doesn't have that car they are still assigned it. When I did it ever car was visually identical (all the same colour).

Although I have a garage of over 200 cars I could only choose from a limited list of cars.

Is there any logic behind this limitation? For example can we only use premium cars in single model races, or maybe cars that the race-host hasn't modified in their own garage?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the list of available cars here:http://www.gtplanet.net/forum/showthread.php?t=206430

It is the same list as "Recommended" Cars - which is also available for arcade.

```
Car PP  Drivetrain
Pagani : Zonda R '09     651     MR
Chevrolet : Impala #24 Jeff Gordon NASCAR '10    630
Chevrolet : Impala #88 Dale Earnhardt, Jr. NASCAR '10   630
HKS : CT230R '08     609     4WD
Nissan : Calsonic Impul GT-R '08     595     FR
Mine's : BNR34 Skyline GT-R N1 Base '06  592     4WD
Toyota : Castrol Tom's Supra '97     591     FF
HPA MOTORSPORTS : FT565 Twin Turbo Audi TT   577     4WD
Citroën : GT by Citroën Road Car     567    
McLaren : McLaren MP4-12C '10    566     MR
Mercedes-Benz : SLS AMG '10  559     FR
AEM : S2000  558     FR
High End Performance : G37  553  FR
Lamborghini : Gallardo LP560-4 '08  546  4WD
Grand Touring Garage : 1970 Ford Mustang "Trans-Cammer" 544  FR
Shelby : Cobra 427 '66  536  FR
Art Morrison : Corvette '60 534 
Amuse : Nismo 380RS Super Leggera   532  FR
Nissan : GT-R '07   529  4WD
Ferrari : F40 '92   527  MR
Audi : R8 4.2 FSI R-Tronic '07  515  4WD
Jaguar : XKR Coupe '10  512  FR
Lexus : IS-F '07    510  FR
Suzuki : SX4 WRC '08    510  4WD
Citroën : C4 WRC '08    508  4WD
Ford : Focus RS WRC07 '08   508  4WD
Aston Martin : DB9 Coupe '06    505  FR
Chevrolet : Camaro SS '10   498  FR
TVR: Tamora '02 498  FR
Dodge : Challenger SRT8 '08 490  FR
Maserati : GranTurismo S '08    489  FR
BMW : M3 Coupe '07  488  FR
Mazda : RX-7 Spirit-R Type-A (FD) '02   466  FR
Subaru : Impreza Sedan WRX STI '10  465  4WD
Mitsubishi : Lancer Evolution X GSR Premium '07 463  4WD
Tesla : Tesla Roadster '08  463  MR
Isuzu : 4200R Concept '89   459  MR
Lotus : Elise 111R '04  447  MR
Ford : Mustang V8 GT Coupe Premium '07  443  FR
Volvo : C30 R-Design '09    415  FF
Renaultsport : Megane Renault Sport '08 414  FF
Alfa Romeo : Brera Sky Window 3.2 JTS Q4 '06    409  4WD
Volkswagen : Golf V GTI '05 405  FF
Lancia : Delta HF Integrale Evoluzione '91  401  4WD
Mini : Mini Cooper S '07    395  FF
Peugeot : 207 GTI '07   394  FF
Spoon : Spoon CR-Z  375 
Honda : CR-Z '10    356  FF
Suzuki : Swift Sport '07    350  FF
Toyota : Prius G '09    316  FF
Daihatsu : Copen Active Top '02 306  FF
Fiat : 500 F '68    223  RR
```

Answer (score -1):

Zonda R (very very powerful but drains fuel too quickly),the vettel prototype(whatever it's called.),Ferrari F10 (its a f1 car),Citroen GT Race Car (it might not be surprisingly good),Xanavi Nismo GT-R (a racing Datsun),Mclaren MP4-12C (sounds like a typewriter model) or maybe a classic Jaguar XJ13 race car/Jaguar XJ220/Jaguar E type (all are very old but does not break down(hopefully).)